# Change color of numbers of sections

Tags: sectioning, formatting, color, titlesec

I want to change this box in which I have the `section` number to black, which I can do. But then the text is the same color and illegible. I need to make it white. I tried this but it didn't do anything.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.3}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\llap{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[3em][r]  {\thesection}}\hspace{1em}}{\textbf{\textcolor{white}{\thesection}}}}
{-0.5em}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no need to print the section number twice. Hence I would change the third argument of the `\titleformat` command to

```
{\llap{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[3em][r]{\textcolor{white}{\thesection}}}\hspace{1em}}}
```

and use `{0pt}` as fourth argument to align the section title with the text body.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.3}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\llap{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[3em][r]{\textcolor{white}{\thesection}}}\hspace{1em}}}
{0pt}
{#1}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. This works too. I guess the picture is a little different. The section doesn't end up coming twice. I was confusing the ToC with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\textcolor{white}{\Roman{section}}}  

\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.3}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\llap{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[3em][r]  {\thesection}}\hspace{1em}}    {\textbf{\textcolor{white}{\thesection}}}}
{-0.5em}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\textcolor{white}{\Roman{section}}}    

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe, this would appear in the `ToC` as well, i.e. the `\thesection` would print white numbers (which means they aren't visible at all)